# Sorting through two dictionaries

Tags: python, strings, hash-map

What my code try to do here is to sort items trough 2 dictionaries. If they are similar or the same, I create a new list to append them.

The test file is relatively big, around 2000 data each dictionary.

My concern is that i need to maintain a linear time complexity trough out the code and i am not sure that my code is on a linear complexity.

I would like an opinion on the complexity of this code. Is it linear? If it is not is there any way to improve it?

```
import pandas as pd
import string
import textdistance as td
import time
start_time = time.time()


amazon =  pd.read_csv('amazon.csv')
google = pd.read_csv('google.csv')

title1 = amazon['title']
title2 = google['name']
id1 = amazon['idAmazon']
id2 = google['id']

out_amazon = {}
out_google = {}

list_a =[]
list_b =[]
list_c =[]
list_d =[]
list_e =[]
list_f =[]
list_g =[]
list_h =[]
list_i =[]
list_j =[]
list_k =[]
list_l =[]
list_m =[]
list_n =[]
list_o =[]
list_p =[]
list_q =[]
list_r =[]
list_s =[]
list_t =[]
list_u =[]
list_v =[]
list_w =[]
list_x =[]
list_y =[]
list_z =[]
list_unknown = []
duplicate_list = []

amazon_labeled = ([(name, 'Amazon') for name in title1])
google_labeled = ([(name, 'Google') for name in title2])

amazon_dict = dict(zip(amazon.idAmazon, amazon_labeled))
google_dict = dict(zip(google.id, google_labeled))

z = {**amazon_dict, **google_dict}
keys = sorted((z.values()))

i = 0
while i < (len(keys)) - 1:
    if (keys[i][0][0]) == 'a':
        list_a.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'b':
        list_b.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'c':
        list_c.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'd':
        list_d.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'e':
        list_e.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'f':
        list_f.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'g':
        list_g.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'h':
        list_h.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'i':
        list_i.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'j':
        list_j.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'k':
        list_k.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'l':
        list_l.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'm':
        list_m.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'n':
        list_n.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'o':
        list_o.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'p':
        list_p.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'q':
        list_q.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'r':
        list_r.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 's':
        list_s.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 't':
        list_t.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'u':
        list_u.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'v':
        list_v.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'w':
        list_w.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'x':
        list_x.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'y':
        list_y.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'z':
        list_z.append(keys[i])
    else:
        list_unknown.append(keys[i])
    i += 1

def check_based_alphabet(alphabetList, k = 0, j = 0):
    while k < len(alphabetList) - 1:
        if alphabetList[k][1] != alphabetList[j][1]:
            distance = td.jaccard(alphabetList[k][0], alphabetList[j][0])
            if distance > 0.7:
                duplicate_list.append([alphabetList[k][0], alphabetList[j][0]])
            j += 1
        else:
            j += 1
        if j == len(alphabetList):
            j = 1
            k += 1            

check_based_alphabet(list_a)
check_based_alphabet(list_b)
check_based_alphabet(list_c)
check_based_alphabet(list_d)
check_based_alphabet(list_e)
check_based_alphabet(list_f)
check_based_alphabet(list_g)
check_based_alphabet(list_h)
check_based_alphabet(list_i)
check_based_alphabet(list_j)
check_based_alphabet(list_k)
check_based_alphabet(list_l)
check_based_alphabet(list_m)
check_based_alphabet(list_n)
check_based_alphabet(list_o)
check_based_alphabet(list_p)
check_based_alphabet(list_q)
check_based_alphabet(list_r)
check_based_alphabet(list_s)
check_based_alphabet(list_t)
check_based_alphabet(list_u)
check_based_alphabet(list_v)
check_based_alphabet(list_w)
check_based_alphabet(list_x)
check_based_alphabet(list_y)
check_based_alphabet(list_z)
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How to get the best value out of CR: Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles. Also, while it isn't exactly a mirror scenario [the consensus is that questions about the complexity of code are off-topic](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8373/120114)

Comment: sorted() takes O(nlog(n)) time, so not linear.

Comment: @LeoAdberg do you mean sorted() in keys = sorted((z.values())) ? Lets set i change it into keys = z.values(). Would this change anything ? Because i don't really need to sort them in the first place

Comment: @Bobby Anyone that actually want to help you learn about big o wouldn't just give you the answer. Why do _you_ think it's linear? Where are your workings out?

Comment: If all you wanna know Is the time complexity of your code, then you've come to the wrong place. If you dont know how to determine that from the code itself, why dont you try the obvious naive solution and make some meassurements for various input sizes and see if it scales lineary?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it poses a specific question, there is no request for review. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

Even if you didn't ask, I would just go ahead and comment on the code.
Please use the following so that you don't need so many lists.

Initialize a dictionary:

```
list_dict = {}

for i in range (97, 123):
    list_dict[chr(i)] = []
```

First use a dictionary:

```
i = 0
while i < (len(keys)) - 1:
    if 'a' <= (keys[i][0][0]) <= 'z':
        list_dict[keys[i][0][0]].append(keys[i])
    else:
        #ignore
        pass
    i += 1
```

And second use loop.

```
for alpha, ll in list_dict.items():
    check_based_alphabet(ll)
```

Comment: While I agree that the code should be vastly simplified, your solution overwrites the entries instead of grouping them by their first letter.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. just wrote that quickly by mistake. corrected.